# Iterate over list taking three items at a time

Tags: python

If I have a list with:

```
["A","Bb","C","D","E","F","G"]
```

how can I iterate over it so that I can output the following:

```
"A Bb C"
"D E F"
"G"
```

Comment: "C" should be output twice?

Comment: @Haidro `"G"` was *over(ite)rated*..

Comment: And what's the logic?

Comment: @Haidro Sorry, I've fixed my question

Answer (score 7):

Is a recipe that I keep hanging around.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

Comment: I like this the best so far but is there any way to use the itertools functions?

Comment: Not directly. This might be a nice addition to itertools.

Comment: @NoelEvans Just added one :)

Answer (score 6):

Get sublists of `[0:3]`, `[3:6]`, `[6:9]`, ...

```
>>> xs = ["A","Bb","C","D","E","F","G"]
>>> [' '.join(xs[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(xs), 3)]
['A Bb C', 'D E F', 'G']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) here:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> L = ["A","Bb","C","D","E","F","G"]
>>> for item in izip_longest(*[iter(L)]*3, fillvalue=''):
...     print ' '.join(item)
... 
A Bb C
D E F
G
```

Comment: Looks more "magical" than writing it simply

Comment: the problem is that the last item is `('G', '', '')` and produces `'G  '`

Comment: @newtover If this is a problem, you can always call `strip()` at the end :)